# Concatenating/Merging all excel files within a folder into a single, new excile file

Tags: python, excel

I am attempting to combine numerous excel files in the same folder into a single, new file using Python. All of the excel files contain time series data, each only has one worksheet, and all have the same layout:

```
Timestamp   -----  Data Tag

TS1       -----------------      ###

TS2        -----------------      ###

etc.

The new combined sheet would look something like this:

Timestamp ----- Data Tag 1-----Data Tag 2

TS1 ----------------- ###----------------###

TS2 ----------------- ###----------------###
```

etc.

I have tried a couple of different methods.

Method 1 only returns the columns from the last file in the list:

```
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    
    all_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in glob.glob("*.xls"):
        print(f)
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        all_data = pd.concat([df])
        all_data.to_excel('destination.xlsx')
        
    print("done")
```

Whereas Method 2 only concatenates the first two files in the folder. It also includes the timestamp column from the second excel file, but I was going to sort out that issue when I got it working for the whole lot.

```
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    
    all_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in glob.glob("*.xls"):
        print(f)
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        all_data = df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        all_data.to_excel('destination.xlsx')
        
    print("done")
```

I searched around, both on SO and elsewhere, but I am struggling to combine these files in the method specified above. Appending is simple, merging for some reason isn't.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you.

EDIT:

Per AMC's comment, edited the code to iterate through files. Now, however, a KeyError is passed as "Timestamp" is not recognized despite calling for no suffixes.

Error:

```
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1706, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'Timestamp'
```

Code causing error:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

rootdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
files = os.listdir(rootdir)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".xls"):
        print(f)
        df = df.merge(pd.read_excel(f), suffixes=None, left_on='Timestamp', right_on='Timestamp')

df.to_excel('concat.xlsx')
    
print("done")
```

Comment: _Method 1 only returns the columns from the last file in the list:_ That's because you're overwriting the file each time you iterate. _Whereas Method 2 only concatenates the first two files in the folder._ Same issue.

Comment: Hey @AMC, thanks for your comment! I made a couple changes to iterate through the files, however the code is now throwing an error as it doesn't appear to recognize the timestamp column of my data. If I instead pass _left_index_=True and _right_index_=True, the code compiles and runs, however only the column labels make it to the final sheet.  Do you have any suggestions on how to work through this?

Comment: That's another issue entirely then, no?